# how to separate levels in a variable with conditions in R

Tags: r, split, conditional-statements

I have this levels for ages and dates:

```
levels(ringing$Edad)
[1] "0" "1" "2" "3" "4" "5" "6" "7" "8" "9"

levels(ringing$bimonth)
[1] "Jan-Feb" "Mar-Apr" "May-Jun" "Jul-Aug" "Sep-Oct" "Nov-Dec"
```

And I need to create a new variable like that one:

```
Grupo_de_edad <-
  data.frame(Edad = levels(ringing$Edad),
             Grupodeedad = c("Unknown", "Unknown", "Unknown", "Juveniles", "Adults",
                             "Adults", "Adults", "Adults", "Adults", "Adults"))
```

But instead of having 10 levels I need to split the level number 5 in:

5A:

```
ringing$Edad ==  "5" & ringing$bimonth == "Jan-Feb"
```

5B:

```
ringing$Edad ==  "5" &
  ringing$bimonth == "Mar-April" |
  ringing$bimonth == "Jun-Jul" |
  ringing$bimonth == "Sep-Oct" |
  ringing$bimonth == "Nov-Dec"
```

I am a beginner in programming with `R`, any suggestions about how could I do the subset will be much appreciated.

Comment: Please, [provide a sample of your data](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

For simplicity, we can use `case_when` from `dplyr`

```
 library(dplyr)
  df %>% mutate(Edad_new = case_when(
            Edad == 5 & bimonth %in% c("Jan-Feb") ~ "5A",
            Edad == 5 & bimonth %in% c("Mar-April", "Jun-Jul", "Sep-Oct", "Nov-Dec" ) ~ "5B",
            TRUE ~ as.character(Edad
    )
))  %>% mutate_if(is.integer,as.factor)  #Change columns with class integer to factor
```

Data:

```
df <- data.frame(Edad = 0:9, bimonth = c("Jan-Feb", "Mar-Apr", "May-Jun", "Jul-Aug", "Sep-Oct", "Nov-Dec", "Jan-Feb", "Mar-Apr", "May-Jun", "May-Jun"))
```

Comment: Sorry but i get this message: Error in `df %>% mutate(ringing, Edad_new = case_when(Edad == 5 & bimonth %in% ` : 
  could not find function "%>%"

Comment: Sorry it is my fault, I should call `library(dplyr)` before the solution. But do not forget google is your friend, just copy past the error message to google and sure you will get a hint in the worst case scenario.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could use something like this:

```
library(tidyverse)    
Grupo_de_edad <- Grupo_de_edad %>%
      mutate(
        Edad_r = if_else(bimonth == "Jan-Feb",paste0(Edad,"A"),paste0(Edad,"B"))
      )
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally a friend suggested me this:

`r<-ringing
r$Edad <- as.character(r$Edad)
r[r$Edad == 5 & r$bimonth=="Jan-Feb",]$Edad <- "5J"
str(r)`

And It works!